# How to pay in euros from the US?

Tags: usa, europe, france, money

I am planning a trip to France from the US, and need to make multiple payments in € on-line, including but not limited to train tickets on https://www.oui.sncf/.
Of course, the easiest way to pay those expanses is to use a credit card, but, from my experience,

1. American credit cards are not often accepted by European websites, (for troubles relative to [oui.sncf](https://www.oui.sncf/), cf. [1](https://www.seat61.com/websites/voyages-sncf.htm#Credit_card_rejection) , [2](https://minimalist.travel/en/reviews/france-train-tickets-international-credit-card/), [3](https://thesavvybackpacker.com/purchase-train-tickets-europe/), or [4](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73190/51569).)
2. The exchange rate applied by the bank is often to the disadvantage of the client,
3. Some (hidden or not) fees may apply.

I don't mean to endorse them in any way, but converting $ into € using https://transferwise.com/ had been the cheapest solution by a long shot in the past for me.
Unfortunately, they don't provide credit cards.

I believe a way of getting a good exchange rate and little-to-no fees would be to buy a pre-paid visa card in € using $ transferred from transferwise (or the like).

However, I haven't found a way of buying a pre-paid visa card using a wire transfer: does that even exist?

Comment: Does it even exist? Yes, they do, there are dozens and dozens. They come and go, too. If you look at the Entropay webpage it's crystal clear they are about to shut down "we are no longer accepting registrations and existing users are not be able to top up their accounts". Cautiously, I'd say Worldcore is perhaps the most promising but a complex user interface is impending their progress. This is _not_ an endorsement of them. Your money, your loss. Here's a [list](https://gomedici.com/top-12-prepaid-debit-cards-available-in-europe-for-hassle-free-and-secure-cross-border-use/) of a dozen.

Comment: Actually, Transferwise do offer the option of a card coupled with their borderless account, but it may only be available to people who reside in the EU at the moment. However, other than the currency exchange / foreign transaction fee, there shouldn't be a problem using a US card on french sites, especially if you are enrolled in 3D Secure.

Comment: I'm surprised to hear that American credit cards are not often accepted by European websites - I'd expect *any* VISA or MASTERCARD affiliated credit card to be accepted almost anywhere in Europe or on websites operated by European businesses.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick There's always the issue of retailers that have been burned by fraud before and will block some cards based on whatever criteria they think is relevant, including the country. In the specific case of SNCF, there's the issue that if you have a ticket which you need to get printed at an automated kiosk, those will ask for the card for validation, and I believe they only accept chip&pin cards, which may be an issue for some US cards. Not sure if there are any restrictions if you have a mobile/electronic ticket, though.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Apparently, American and Australian cards are commonly rejected by oui.sncf.com, cf. https://www.seat61.com/websites/voyages-sncf.htm#Credit_card_rejection , https://minimalist.travel/en/reviews/france-train-tickets-international-credit-card/, https://thesavvybackpacker.com/purchase-train-tickets-europe/, or https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73190/51569.

Comment: Get a Revolut card.

Comment: @JoErNanO Thanks, but they're not open to the US market yet. They have a waiting list, but they've been working on it for almost 2 years (!), cf. https://community.revolut.com/t/revolut-lands-in-the-usa/12406/280

Comment: I've used my [USAA](https://www.usaa.com/inet/wc/banking_credit_cards_main) VISA card with no problems on the websites of French and German hotels and via physical presence in France, Italy, Germany, and the Netherlands, including buying tickets at German and Dutch rail station kiosks. Note: I requested a PIN from USAA before I began my travels.

Comment: @shoover In their [contract](https://content.usaa.com/mcontent/static_assets/Media/credit_card_combined_agreement_with_pricing_arbitration_addendums.pdf?cacheid=3995800721_p), USAA writes: "When you make a transaction in a foreign currency, it will be converted into U.S. Dollars by either: (a) MasterCard, American Express, or Visa or (b) the merchant or its agent. We do not convert your transactions into U.S. Dollars, and we are not responsible for the conversion rates or processes used by the person who does". That seems pretty uncertain to me, and likely to give unfair exchange rates.

Comment: @Clément: The card network (MasterCard, American Express, or Visa) exchange rates are somewhere between very good and very very very good.  If you let the merchant convert, you'll be cheated.

Answer (score 5):

I have never had a problem using my Schwab visa on websites for Renfe (Spanish trains) or airlines based in Spain, Turkey, and elsewhere.  Nor for any hotels.  Never tried SNCF.  I did use it to buy a train ticket on loco2.com which should also be able to book SNCF.

Schwab is one of several banks that charges no exchange fee.  They use whatever rate Visa uses, which is a hair higher than transferwise.  Many sites also accept PayPal, which lets you choose the currency but not at a great rate.

Comment: I have had a similar experience. 10 or 15 years ago I would run into problems with European web sites that would not accept a US card, but these days I never have a problem. In particular, travel related websites seem pretty geared up for international payments.

Comment: @LaconicDroid Websites, yes, but not vending machines. Many train ticket vending machines in Europe have a hard time with foreign cards, even sometimes from another EU country. In France, I think the current situation is that if you buy a ticket online to be printed by a vending machine, you need a card with a chip (a few years ago, it had to be a French card). Most tickets can now be shown on your smartphone or printed at home, but not all of them.

Comment: @Gilles - right, but the OP says "and need to make multiple payments in € on-line" so I was discussing only online payments.

Comment: @LaconicDroid in the case of SNCF, some tickets, even though ordered online, need to be printed at an automated vending machine (or using the services of a human teller, but that usually requires queueing). The machine will need the card just for verification (it will not actually debit anything, it just requires the card and the PIN for a 0.00 EUR charge).

Comment: My card also worked fine for machines in Korea, Taiwan, Spain, U.K.  Didn’t work in China but that was because they demanded a six-digit pint and mine is only four digits.

Comment: I actually had many issues trying to use my Schwab Visa Debit card in all sorts of payment kiosks, like for parking or train tickets. I was quite disappointed, the fee-free part is nice, but if the card won't process, it doesn't help. This was in western Europe 2 years ago.

Comment: From 2013 through 2019, my Schwab debit card always worked in Asia and Europe for ATMs, ticket purchases, shopping, etc.  Turkey, Taiwan, Korea, Ireland, UK, Spain, France, Gibraltar, Portugal, Italy, Andorra, San Marino, Switzerland, Germany, Netherlands, Belgium, Austria, Liechtenstein, Canada, Iceland, Mexico, Perú, USA …

Answer (score 2):

Some online banks provide the solutions you need, like [WeSwap](https://www.weswap.com) or [Revolut](https://www.revolut.com) : For less than $10, you can get a Mastercard, top it up in your local currency and spend it in (almost) any foreign currencies.

I have one of them and I already bought a SNCF train ticket with it (and also some flight tickets in EU), I never get any trouble.

Comment: Another vote for Revolut - I'm in the UK and I I've used it to make US$ payments online, AUS$ payments and cash withdrawals whilst travelling in Australia and AED payments while on layover at airports in the United Arab Emirates. Never had any problems, no fees, and the exchange rates have always been very competitive.

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but I thought I'd comment on what I ended up doing:

- For most of the expenses, I paid cash using euros that I withdrew using my US cards. The exchange rate was fair, and there was little fee (ranging from $1 to $5 per withdraw, but some of the fees were actually refunded at the end of the month).
- For some (larger) expenses, I paid using my US card: same deal (fair exchange fee, low or no fees).
- For the on-line payment at https://www.oui.sncf/, I asked someone with a French credit card to do it for me. For most of the tickets, I obtained e-tickets that I could print myself, but in one case I had no choice but to get the ticket at the station using the card used to pay: in that scenario, having used my US card would have been problematic.